# How to insert multiple row with different ID in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need a way to insert multiple rows into sql table, and return all inserted different primary key ids with one sql query.

```
foreach($request->size as $key => $value)
{
    $size = new sizes;
    $size->size_name = $request->size[$key];
    $size->size_price = $request->sizeprice[$key];
    $size->pid = $last_id;
    $size->save();
        
    $size_last_id = $size->id;
}
    


foreach($request->stock as $key => $value)
{
    $stock = new stocks;
    $stock->pid = $last_id;
    $stock->size_id = $size_last_id;
    $stock->stock_qty = $request->stock[$key];
    $stock->save();
}
```

Please find the attached this image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsJHZ.png

Answer (score 0):

```
$size_last_id = $size->id;
```

Above code will return only last inserted row's id as you are inserting data using foreach loop.

Better to store all the ids in an array, declare a variable as an array and push id to array.

**Sample code.**

```
$size_last_id = [];

foreach($request->size as $key => $value)
{
    $size = new sizes;
    $size->size_name = $request->size[$key];
    $size->size_price = $request->sizeprice[$key];
    $size->pid = $last_id;
    $size->save();
        
    array_push($size_last_id, $size->id);
}
```

This will store all the inserted ids to array.

[Read More about array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Thank you. Im trying to save an array to the database but the error "array to string conversion" is appearing